# Angular filter throwing "Can't interpolate" error even though the filter works

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the below filter (why I got from StackOverflow) which works on one page, but throws the below error on another (using the same object).

```
app.filter('dateFormat', function dateFormat($filter){
  return function(text){
    var  tempdate= new Date(text.replace(/-/g,"/"));
    return $filter('date')(tempdate, "dd-MM-yyyy");
  }
});

Can't interpolate: {{ job.job_date | dateFormat}}
TypeError: text is undefinedO/<@http://localhost/ef-serial-numbers/public/assets/global/plugins/angularjs/angular.min.js:6:412Ka.interr@http://localhost/ef-serial-numbers/public/assets/global/plugins/angularjs
```

If I change `job.job_date` to a hardcoded date, the error disappears. The thing is, the filter is actually working correctly regardless of the error.

Comment: Maybe check if `text` is undefined before calling `.replace` ?

Comment: I believe the comment from @MMHunter is correct as the solution; the reason for this behaviour is (probably, just guessing) that the `job.job_date` starts `undefined`, but then quickly gets a value; the first digest throws the exception, the second displays the correct value and the filter apparently "works".

Comment: @Lock with pleasure xD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe check if `text` is undefined before calling `.replace`.

Since at the very beginning, the filter function may be called before `job.job_date` gets its value.